# Split working address of company in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

My string looks like:

```
"WIERZBOWA 21, 67-200 GŁOGÓW"
```

I would like to have three variables of string:

```
1. address: "WIERZBOWA 21"
2. zipCode: "67-200"
3. city: "GŁOGÓW"
```

I can do it with split, but I'd like to do it stylishly with object destructing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The code you're using makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern engines support named capture groups, which may be what you're looking for:

```js
const str = "WIERZBOWA 21, 67-200 GŁOGÓW";
const match = str.match(/^(?<address>[^,]+), (?<zipCode>\S+) (?<city>\S+)$/);
console.log(match.groups);
```

Another method, without named groups, and destructuring into individual variables:

```js
const str = "WIERZBOWA 21, 67-200 GŁOGÓW";
const [, address, zipCode, city] = str.match(/^([^,]+), (\S+) (\S+)$/);
console.log(address, zipCode, city);
```